# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module NextJs and Gulp

Tags: reactjs, next.js, gulp, es6-modules, i18next

I'm trying to implement `i18n-perser` with Next Js. According to the `i18n-perser` documentation I need to create a `gulpfile.js` on the root directory. My `gulpfile.js` is something like this. When I'm running `npm run gulp` It's gives me `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

```
import gulp from 'gulp';
import { gulp as i18nextParser } from 'i18next-parser';

export async function i18next() {
  return gulp
    .src('./**')
    .pipe(
      new i18nextParser({
        locales: ['en', 'nl'],
        output: './i18n/locales/$LOCALE/$NAMESPACE.json',
      })
    )
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
}
```

I tried some solution like the `next dynamic import`. But it's not working for me in this case. It's giving me the same `SyntaxError`.

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
const gulp = dynamic(() => import('gulp'), { ssr: false });
const { gulp: i18nextParser } = dynamic(() => import('i18next-parser"'), { ssr: false });
```

I also tried anothe solution, I renamed the `gulpfile.js` to `gulpfile.mjs`. After renaming it's starting. But it's giving me another error. `FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory.`

I18n-perser is working perfectly in React but not working with NextJs. Basiclly if I `run npm run` gulp it should create parer file for me.